# pointer to reference use ctypes

Tags: python, c++

My cpp program:test.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

extern "C"
{
    void test_2(int &e, int *&f)
    {
        e=10;
        f=new int[e];
        for(int i=0;i<e;i++)
            f[i]=i;
    }
}
```

And this is my compile command:`g++ -fPIC -shared test.cpp -o test.so`
my operating system is ubuntu 12.04 lts,my python version is 2.7.5,the python program like these:

```
#coding=utf-8

import ctypes
from ctypes import *

if __name__ == "__main__":
    lib = ctypes.CDLL("./test.so")
    a = c_int()
    b = c_int()
    lib.test_2(
        byref(a),
        byref(pointer(b))
    )
    print a.value
    print type(b)
```

and the output is `10` and `<class 'ctypes.c_int'>`,but I wanna get the number 10 and an int array,what should I do?

Comment: `int *&f is` is not pointer to reference (there is no such thing), but reference to pointer.

Comment: You defined `b = c_int()`. I think you want to define `b` as pointer to int instead. The way you do the call, you let `test_2` overwrite the temporary created by `pointer(b)`.

Comment: Ya, `b = POINTER(c_int())` and then pass as `byref(b)` looks better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define **b** as a pointer in the first place.

```
#coding=utf-8

import ctypes
from ctypes import *

if __name__ == "__main__":
    lib = ctypes.CDLL("./test.so")
    a = c_int()
    b = pointer(c_int())
    lib.test_2(
        byref(a),
        byref(b)
    )
    for index in range(0,a.value):
      print b[index]
```

Comment: I would appreciate an explanation from the downvoter

Comment: I am so sorry,I click the downvoter by mistake, and I want to click the upvoter.But the webpage give me a message that I can't upvoter.If you modify your code a little and then give you a upvoter.